# Subgroup structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hello I'm doing Abstract Algebra problems for practice and one of them asks for the subgroup structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$ and the main question I have is what does $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$ mean? I have never seen that notation before. Something tells me it has to do with modulo. Anyway I know it seems like a dumb question and i have googled it but haven't found anything on what it means and my book never mentions it. Thank you for the responses in advance

Answer (score 1):

It means the additive group of integers modulo $32$. You might have seen it written before as $\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/32$. It is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{32}$ with $32$ elements, or equivalently the group with one generator $x$ subject to the relation $x^{32}=1$, i.e. the group presented by $\langle x \mid x^{32}=1 \rangle$.

Pick whichever of the above you prefer, and you'll end up with something equal or isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$.